# Uncorrect result of query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I get 2500 strings after this query

```
`SELECT  t1.type, t1.from_sale,t1.from_sent,t1.on_sent,t2.from_sale,t2.from_sent,t2.on_sent FROM 
(SELECT 
type,from_sale,from_sent,on_sent
FROM deliverability.delivery_money_repo
where add_time >= (CURDATE()-1) AND add_time < CURDATE()) t1,
(SELECT 
from_sale,from_sent,on_sent
FROM deliverability.delivery_money_repo
where add_time >= CURDATE()) t2`
```

But it should be only 50. What I do wrong?
I want to get yesterday and today data.

[image: data]

---

[image: structure]

Comment: How should we know without seeing the table structure, example data and expected output?

Comment: you are doing a inner join between t1 and t2 so: 50 * 50 = 2500. What do you want extract?

Comment: @juergend add data and structure in question.

Comment: You have no join condition.

Comment: @Eomm there is only 50 strings for each date, I want to get yesterday and today data,It should be a total of 50 strings.

Comment: You have got lots and lots of questions on here by now; that's fine, but it really is time you got better at asking them. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a hint of what is going on here. Mysql is doing exactly what your asking. Let me give a simple example:

You have 2 tables:

table1 (id1, value1)

- 1, a
- 2, b
- 3, c

table2 (id2, value2)

- 2, x
- 3, y
- 4, z

Now your telling mysql to get every row from *table1* and every row from *table2* and join them. This is called an implicite join, because you give the database no hint on what to join. What happens is, **every row table1 is joined with every row from table2**. You should add an ON-condition to the join, but you're not doing it. So basically your query is

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
```

I would advise you to use the join syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
```

This will combine every row from *table1* with every row from *table2*. That means you will get 3*3 = 9 rows as a result. Or in your example above 50*50.

If you want to combine two (or more) tables with a condition you should use a ON-condition

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id1=table2.id2
```

That would result in only 2 results, because only id 2 and 3 are in both tables2.

Now to your query. First get rid of the subqueries! You just do not need them (and they can have a bad impact on performance). I guess you want to join based on type. If not, please change the query.

```
`SELECT  t1.type, t1.from_sale,t1.from_sent,t1.on_sent,t2.from_sale,t2.from_sent,t2.on_sent 
 FROM deliverability.delivery_money_repo t1
 JOIN deliverability.delivery_money_repo t2 
      ON t2.type=t1.type AND t2.add_time >= CURDATE()
 WHERE t1.add_time >= (CURDATE()-1) AND add_time < CURDATE()
```

See the ON-condition which makes t2 only have add_time from today (works a bit like a where condition here) and give a condition for the join, so you do not make an implicite join. The database will now only join the rows if type is identical for table1 and table2.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get yesterday and today data you should rethink your condition.

I will use your condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM deliverability.delivery_money_repo
WHERE 
    -- yesterday
    (add_time >= (CURDATE()-1) AND add_time < CURDATE())
    OR
    -- or today
    (add_time >= CURDATE())
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT *  
FROM deliverability.delivery_money_repo
WHERE add_time >= (CURDATE()-1)
```

You extract 2500 row because you are doing an [implicit join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) and you multiply your yesterday's record * your today records.

If you execute your two subqueries separately, and use [union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html), you will extract 50 records.

Comment: The term you're looking for is [`cross join`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) (or cartesian join). Yes the cross join happens to be implicit because of the way the query is written. But being "implicit" isn't the problem - an explicit cross join (as in `FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2`) would produce exactly the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Don't enumerate the data-tables you want to access with just a symbol ',' in the 'FROM' clause.

Because you don't even know what kind of behavior the database server will do when it read the 'FROM' clause in the SQL instruction.

And views are considered as a kind of temporary data-tables in the relational-database theory.

Maybe the database will execute an implicit join.
Maybe the database will consider the SQL instruction as an error.
Maybe ......

So use join explicitly if you need to do.

---

The two sub-queries in your SQL instruction would create two views(2 temporary data-tables) in the data-set computation.

And the two views seemed to be joined as a Cartesian product.
(Or another type of join operation.)

A Cartesian product contains all the possible combinations between the two data-tables(or views).
Consequently, if you join a data-table itself which contains N rows as a Cartesian product, then the number of the rows in the result-set would be N*N.

For example,

T1 :

```
    C1   |  C2 
   -------------
   r1c1  | r1c2 
   r2c1  | r2c2
```

T2 :

```
 C1 
-----
r1c1
r2c1
```

The Cartesian product of the data-tables T1 & T2 would be :

```
 T1.C1     |    T1.C2    |      T2.C1 
---------------------------------------
T1.r1c1    |   T1.r1c2   |     T2.r1c1 
T1.r1c1    |   T1.r1c2   |     T2.r2c1 
T1.r2c1    |   T1.r2c2   |     T2.r1c1 
T1.r2c1    |   T1.r2c2   |     T2.r2c1
```

---

Because I don't know what your requirement is, I can not write a recommended SQL instruction for you currently.

If it was necessary to join the two views which were created from the two sub-queries, then you could try 'inner-join', 'left outer-join', or 'right outer-join', or 'full outer-join' EXPLICITLY.